# Why are my Android gradle variant customisations not working?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

1- Why is the following:

```
android.buildVariants.each { variant ->
    ... my code
}
```

giving me the following error?

> Could not find property 'buildVariants' on com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@1bf6bde6.

2- Why is the following silently not executing "... my code"?

```
android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
    ... my code
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. The Android Build System now uses "applicationVariants" instead of "buildVariants". However, "android.applicationVariants.each" will also not work, see below.
2. Since the Android Build System 0.5.5 release you must use "android.applicationVariants.all" instead of "android.applicationVariants.each", as applicationVariants will remain [empty with a call to each](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system).